# Выдает две ошибки в untiy 2d

Tags: unity3d

**первая **ошибка****

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animator' attached to the "alienBlue_stand" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Animator to the game object "alienBlue_stand". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before usi**ng it.
UnityEngine.Animator.SetInteger (System.String name, System.Int32 value) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Animation/ScriptBindings/Animator.bindings.cs:352)
Player.CheckGround () (at Assets/New Folder/Player.cs:55)
Player.Update () (at Assets/New Folder/Player.cs:23)
```

**вторая ошибка**

```
ArgumentException: Input Axis horizontal is not setup.
 To change the input settings use: Edit -> Settings -> Input
Player.Update () (at Assets/New Folder/Player.cs:24)
```

**Вот код**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    public float jumpheight;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    bool isgrounded;
    Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CheckGround();
        if (Input.GetAxis("horizontal") == 0 &&  isgrounded)
        {
            anim.SetInteger("state", 1);
        } 
        else
        {
            Flip();
            if (isgrounded)
                anim.SetInteger("state", 2);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isgrounded)
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpheight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

     void Flip()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
    }
    void CheckGround()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundCheck.position, 0.2f);
        isgrounded = colliders.Length > 1;
        if (!isgrounded)
            anim.SetInteger("state", 3);
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста я только начал изучать.

Comment: Вижу куски кода из интернетов, которые ты кое-как переписал не понимая что к чему. Начни лучше последовательно, с основ, в интернете полно курсов.

Comment: Не согласен, тк я по курсу все делал одному где с основ про unity 2d и с#

Comment: И твой комментарий очень информативный, спасибо

Comment: Ну тогда, ты сможешь просто воспользоваться [Translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru), что бы узнать в чём ошибки, где ошибка и как её исправить.